No ContractEndDate access at all for Admin on order
I have no access to ContractEndDate on Order.
I am an admin, the admin profile has full access to the order object and read access to ContractEndDate.
I have  a permission set with full access to the order object and read access to the ContractEndDate.
I have tried with Auto-calculate Contract End Date set to true and to false.
I have double checked everything a thousand times. Would anyone know what the issue could be?
Thanks in advance.

Check if this may help you. - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A93vGSAR and -https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_order_permissions.htm&type=5

@TusharJadav This does not really apply to me. I am the admin, with permissions for this field but still i have niether read nor edit access.
